# How to create and use a module that implement 64 bit (only) static library

Tags: ios, module, appcelerator, hockeyapp

**Has anyone successfully created and used a module that implements a 64 bit (only) static library?**

Here the situation:

Created a new Appcelerator module project

- Downloaded the latest HockeySDK-iOS framework (64 bit only)
- Integrated HockeyApp HockeySDK-iOS into my module project
- build iOS module project no problem
- build (package) appcelerator module no problem (build.py)
- create new appcelerator ios App project 5.2.2GA
- install module (.zip) into App project
- **#ERROR** Building the app project...

  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

The HockeySDK appear to only be built for 64 bit support. I played around with the Architecture flags in my module project - but the Appcelerator app build seems to require the i386 x86_64 architecture.

**Or has anyone implemented a current version of HockeyApp SDK for ios?**

Please do not suggest: https://github.com/timanrebel/HockeyApp as that project uses HockeyApp iOS SDK v3.8.5 while the current [HockeyApp SDK version for iOS](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-ios-mac-os-x-tvos/hockeyapp-for-ios) is 4.0

Comment: The HockeySDK-iOS builds do support and come with slices for all architectures!

Comment: Just do `lipo -info HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Versions/A/HockeySDK` and you get the following result: `Architectures in the fat file: /Users/andreaslinde/Downloads/HockeySDK-iOS 2/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Versions/A/HockeySDK are: armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64 arm64`

Comment: @Kerni **Thank you, you are correct!** I stand corrected. I assumed this because of the build error and the HockeyApp SDK release page only shows (  armv7/ armv7s / arm64 ) [https://www.hockeyapp.net/releases/](https://www.hockeyapp.net/releases/)

Answer (score -1):

As my understanding, "the Appcelerator app build seems to require the i386 x86_64 architecture." means your application now config of supporting both i386 and x86_64 architecture. i386 is the architecture of your desktop that will be required if you want to run on simulator. But your HockeySDK-iOS framework (64 bit only) will not suppose to support i386 architecture. As my guess, you got that missing i386 architecture error while running on simulator. Could you try to config your project support 64 bit only and then run the project on your real 64 bit devices.

In order to fix that error, you can remove your i386 architecture support or download again to make sure that all libraries have been built for i386 architecture.